# Open App from a Preference: How to do?

Tags: java, android, xml

i have this Preference

```
<PreferenceScreen android:key="myKey"
                android:title="myTitle">
        </PreferenceScreen>
```

How do i open an App when i Click on this Preference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put

```
intent
```

element inside the

```
PreferenceScreen
```

element:

```
<intent
    android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
    android:targetClass="[activity_name_here]"
    android:targetPackage="[package_name_here]" />
```